# Android Studio imageView coordinates

Tags: android, imageview

Good day all.

I have an image in an imageView and I am using ObjectAnimator to move and rotate the image onscreen. I have a number of x-y coordinates, which are relative to the image inside the imageView. How can I access any given such x-y point despite moving and rotating the image onscreen? Any help would be appreciated.

I am coding in Java.

Paul

Comment: it would help a lot more if you posted the code you currently have

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity

```
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;

public class MainActivity<theMap> extends AppCompatActivity {


   // private static final int LENGTH_SHORT = ;
    private ImageView imageView;

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mymap);


        imageView.animate()
                .scaleX(1)
                .scaleY(1);


    }


    public void onButtonClickRotate(View v) {

        int[] WayPointsX = {433,503,605,668,820,919,1060,1168,1258,1371,1412};
        int[] WayPointsY = {463,478,421,397,367,363,376,400,438,510,543};
     
        ObjectAnimator animX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationX", -750f);
        ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationY", -450f);

     //   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "pivotX", 1500f).start();
     //   ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "pivotY", 0F).start();
     //   ObjectAnimator animR = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "rotation", 0F, 360F);

        AnimatorSet s = new AnimatorSet();

        s.play(animX).with(animY);
       // s.play(animR).after(animY);
        s.setDuration(3000);
        s.start();

       

    }


}

activity_main

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRunRotate"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="onButtonClickRotate"
        android:text="@string/rotate" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mymap"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/themap"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shopper" />



</FrameLayout>
```

Now the two Arrays WayPointsX and WayPointsY are coordinates on the image which I want to step-wise move to. As they stand the coordinate values are from a Javascript code and I am trying to figure out what the values should be in Java bearing in mind that during the animation the onscreen graphic will also be rotating about set pivot points.So the WayPoint Array values are currently just parked there and my code does not use these numbers currently. I achieved this animation with ease in the Javascript build.

The AnimX and AnimY vales of
-750f and -450f are actual points which the java animations take the graphic to. I need to know how to get the values for the required points on the graphic.

I have also realised that I am trying to go to a point on the graphic to an accuracy of a few pixels but find this to be way off and dependent on the emulator I use or the actual device I connect to.

Hope this makes sense.